# Cancel link becomes inactive when "Ask a Question" on Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The cancel link should never become inactive when you try to "Ask a Question" on jobs.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to a job like this one https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/151978/senior-net-developer-triple-i
2. Click the **Not sure, Ask a question** link on the right side near the **Apply** button to ask something about the job
3. Note cancel link is active and I can cancel asking a question initially
4. Type one single letter in the "Add your message" textbox
5. Erase the single letter you just typed in

**What happened:** The cancel button is now disabled

**What should happen:** The cancel button should never get disabled, the only button that should get disabled is the "Send" button.

Comment: To be fair, there is an X at the top to close out of it.....But I get what you're saying.

Comment: Right I understand that you can still ESC or close out of the popup but it is still a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch! thank you for the report, JonH. This should be fixed now.